# How to configure Fitnesse for testing DAL?

Tags: c#, tdd, fitnesse, fitsharp

I am trying to test method in DAL of my web application with Fitnesse and FitSharp. I am having problems with reading app.config.

Getting error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
at ...DAL.get_ConnectionString()
```

This is in getter

```
get{
  var result = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CN1"].ConnectionString;
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) 
        throw new NoNullAllowedException("Connection string does not exist");
  return result;
}
```

> Why ConfigurationManager is not initialized?
>
> How to configure Fitnesse for testing DAL?
>
> Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'd need to [make Fit Sharp aware of your App.config file](http://fitsharp.github.com/FitSharp/AppConfigFile.html):

```
c:\program files\fitsharp\runner -a c:\mypath\myapp.exe.config
   -c c:\myfolder\mysuite.config.xml
   -r fit.Runner.FolderRunner,c:\program files\fitsharp\fit.dll
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I just want to add that app.config is case sensitive with fit runner. Tag ConnectionStrings must starts with lowercase: <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>